# Find the selected segment in a wheel of fortune spinning wheel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in Unity I have a circle sprite that is rotating over time.

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I want to calculate **n** pieces from this circle. Some examples:

[image: examples]

The amount of pieces is given by the length of an array

```
private void SplitCircle(Part[] parts)
{
    // split the circle by the amount of parts
}
```

**I just have to calculate it. I don't need the UI part!**

Each piece would take (360 / n) degrees from the circle. When having 5 pieces the first part should have a range from 0 to 72. The second one from 73 to 144 etc.

In my scene I have a button that stops the rotation of the circle. Is it possible to calculate which part is on top when pressing the button?

[image: stop]

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the circle rotation value to between 0 and 360 (rotation % 360).

Subtract this from each number in each segment's range in turn. For each segment, find the one where the bottom of the adjusted range values are < 0 at the lower bound, and >= 0 at the upper bound. Pick that one.

If the selected segment is out, adjust the pre-normalised rotation value by 90 degrees until the outcome fits with your "up".

Also, your range should not be 0..72, 73..144 etc. What about 72.5 degrees? It should be 72..144 with the lower bound being >= and the upper bound being <.

In untested C#ish pseudocode...

```cs
var adjust = 0; /* Adjust this +/- 90 if the result comes out with the wrong result */
var spriteRotation = (getSpriteRotationDegrees() + adjust) % 360.0f;
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var lowerBound = parts[i].lowerBound() - spriteRotation;
    var upperBound = parts[i].upperBound() - spriteRotation;
    if (lowerBound < 0 && upperBound >= 0) {
        break;
    }
}
var winningPart = parts[i];
```

Comment: sorry would you mind providing some code because I don't know how to convert this into code because I am not good enough in mathematics